# Move series legends below x-axis in highcharts

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I am using highcharts in my angular app. I am using line charts. Chart is as follows:

[line_charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqSM1.png)

Fiddle is as follows:

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic

Code is as follows:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  title: {
    text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
  },

  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
  },

  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Number of Employees'
    }
  },

  xAxis: {
    accessibility: {
      rangeDescription: 'Range: 2010 to 2017'
    }
  },

  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle'
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      label: {
        connectorAllowed: false
      },
      pointStart: 2010
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Installation',
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
  }, {
    name: 'Manufacturing',
    data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
  }, {
    name: 'Sales & Distribution',
    data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
  }, {
    name: 'Project Development',
    data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
  }, {
    name: 'Other',
    data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
  }],

  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 500
      },
      chartOptions: {
        legend: {
          layout: 'horizontal',
          align: 'center',
          verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
      }
    }]
  }

});
```

Code is working fine but I want the legends which I marked in red circle in image attached to come below x-axis. How can I dot that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit `legend` options:

```
  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/18m57rth/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend